# How can I delete key from dictionary in .plist file?

Tags: ios, macos, plist, info.plist, plistbuddy

I want delete key from `IDESourceControlKnownSSHHostsDefaultsKey` dictionary from `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist` file

I wrote there key in this way
`defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESourceControlKnownSSHHostsDefaultsKey -dict-add host 'fingerprint'`

How can i delete this key? Not whole `IDESourceControlKnownSSHHostsDefaultsKey`, but only `host` key from `IDESourceControlKnownSSHHostsDefaultsKey` dictionary

Comment: open it in Xcode, that allows you the modify `.plist` files easily, but I'm sure you can use a simple XML editor or plain text editor for achieveing the same outcome.

Comment: I think you can't do it for the key in a sub-dictionary, so if you need to use `defaults` your only option is to remove the entire dictionary then re-add it with the one key removed.